# Mimetype Error In Webpack Output (using knockout)

Tags: node.js, knockout.js, webpack, mime-types, webpack-dev-server

This is my first time using Knockout. I wanted to use it with node, webpack, and es6 but for some reason the bundle I am creating is causing an error in the browser:

"Refused to execute script from 'http://localhost:8080/build/bundle.js' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled."

My webpack.config.js is:

```
const path = require('path')


module.exports = {
      output: {
        path: path.resolve('build', './bundle.js'),
        filename: 'bundle.js'
      },
      module: {
        loaders: [
        {
          test: /\.html$/, loader: 'html'
        },
          {
            test: /\.js?$/,
            exclude: /(node_modules)/,
            loader: 'babel-loader',

          },
        ]
    }
};
```

package.json file is:

```
{
  "name": "neighborhoodmap",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Neighborhood Map App with API Calls",
  "main": "app.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "dev": "node_modules/webpack-dev-server/bin/webpack-dev-server.js",
    "build": "webpack"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "knockout": "^3.4.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-loader": "^7.1.2",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
    "html-loader": "^0.5.1",
    "imports-loader": "^0.7.1",
    "webpack": "^3.8.1",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^2.9.5"
  }
}
```

The app.js file is:

```
import ko from 'knockout';


class MyApp {
  constructor() {
    this.message = "Hello World";
  }
}

ko.applyBindings(new MyApp())
```

And the actual index.html is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Neighborhood Map</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1 data-bind="text: message"></h1>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="build/bundle.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

I'm serving the app with webpack-dev-server, but even when I just place the index.html in the browser there is still an error with the bundle:

"Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < for build/bundle.js:1"

Is there a way of specifying the mimetype of the bundle output? Or maybe my webpack.config.js is wrong? Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For anybody running into the same problem, I solved mine by including a noParse in the webpack config file under the module property to stop webpack from parsing the knockout build. The final webpackconfig.js file looks like this:

```
const path = require('path');


module.exports = {
    devtool: 'sourcemap',
      entry: './app.js',
      output: {
        path: path.resolve('build', ''),
        filename: 'bundle.js'
      },
      module: {
      noParse: /node_modules\/knockout\/build\/output\/*.js/,
      loaders: [
        {
          test: /\.html$/, loader: 'html'
        },
          {
            test: /\.js?$/,
            exclude: /(node_modules)/,
            loader: 'babel-loader',
            query: {
                presets: ['es2015']
            }
          },
        ]
    }
};
```